# Fredhopper Configuration for Experience Optimization

Tags: fredhopper, web8.5, experience-optimization

I am trying to configure the fredhopper-8.1-revision-1 for web 8.5. 
I am following the [sdl Document](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D) to configure the fredhopper.

As per document the processes are working till setting up the cluster, i.e `bin\setup-cluster` command is working with out any error. But after adding the  Experience Optimization files [configuration-management-rest-extension-1.1.jar,smarttarget_api_extension.jar,metadata.xml, trigger-type.xml etc] in the respective folder as per document I ran the command `bin\instance ExperienceOptimization` . 
But this command runs for 20-30 minutes before finishing with error.

Please find the log files here.

**Agent.log Updated: **

```
  2017-05-31 12:06:37,207 INFO  Installation FAS is FAS version 7.5.1.3 (tags/fas/fas-7.5.1.3/fas-assembly snapshot-109233) (DeploymentAgent.java:290)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,221 INFO  Installation FAS requests factory com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.FASInstallationFactory (DeploymentAgent.java:329)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,241 INFO  Supporting feature com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.DebugFeature using class com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.GenericDebugFeature (FASInstallation.java:111)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,244 INFO  Supporting feature com.fredhopper.deployment.core.ProfilingFeature using class com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.GenericProfilingFeature (FASInstallation.java:111)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,244 INFO  Installation FAS in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS (FASInstallationFactory) (DeploymentAgent.java:97)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,245 INFO  Installation DM is Data Manager version 2.0.4 (fredhopper_data_manager 2.0.4) (DeploymentAgent.java:290)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,247 INFO  Installation DM requests factory com.fredhopper.deployment.dm.DataManagerInstallationFactory (DeploymentAgent.java:329)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,252 INFO  Installation DM in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM (DataManagerInstallationFactory) (DeploymentAgent.java:97)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,503 INFO  Detected 64-bit JVM (DataManagerInstallation.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,507 INFO  Using default preset large for instance etl (Installation.java:194)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,560 INFO  Instance etl created (Installation.java:211)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,560 INFO  Instance etl in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\etl (DeploymentAgent.java:129)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,561 INFO  Detected 64-bit JVM (DataManagerInstallation.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,561 INFO  Using default preset large for instance deployment (Installation.java:194)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,566 INFO  Instance deployment created (Installation.java:211)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,566 INFO  Instance deployment in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment (DeploymentAgent.java:129)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,569 INFO  Deployment Agent 1.1-beta-9 (build dev 2013-09-05 14:43:47) (Main.java:203)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,569 INFO  System: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 (amd64) (Main.java:204)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,569 INFO  Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11) (Main.java:205)
            2017-05-31 12:06:37,580 INFO  Host: dxa.netgear.com (Main.java:235)
            2017-05-31 12:06:38,618 INFO  Started on /0.0.0.0:8177 (ServerRunner.java:53)
            2017-05-31 12:07:56,401 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:07:57,143 INFO  Invoking start with {logLevel=basic, fileName=jobs/setup-cluster.kjb} on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:105)
            2017-05-31 12:07:57,159 INFO  Initialized GenericProcessHelper (Util.java:49)
            2017-05-31 12:07:57,229 INFO  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM -Ddata-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\data -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\config -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log -Dcustom-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\custom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\tmp -Dderby.stream.error.file=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log\bizman.db.log -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.fredhopper.util.prefs.XmlPreferencesFactory -Dhttp.keepAlive=false -DKETTLE_HOME=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment -DKETTLE_USER= -DKETTLE_PASSWORD= -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY= -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\plugins,C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\plugins -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7100 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xmx4000m -Xloggc:C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log\kitchen.gc.log -cp C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\lib\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\hive\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\JDBC\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\pigConf\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\feeds\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\JDBC\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\mondrian\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\mondrian\config\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\pentaho\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\reporting\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\salesforce\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\lib\*; org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -file C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\jobs\setup-cluster.kjb -level Basic -norep (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:08:06,731 INFO  Instance ExperienceOptimization created (Installation.java:211)
            2017-05-31 12:08:06,733 INFO  Instance ExperienceOptimization created in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization (DeploymentAgent.java:539)
            2017-05-31 12:08:06,747 INFO  Copied 603/-1 bytes (InputStreamSerializer.java:85)
            2017-05-31 12:08:06,797 INFO  Added role staging to instance ExperienceOptimization (Instance.java:232)
            2017-05-31 12:08:08,294 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:08:11,391 INFO  Instance ExperienceOptimizationLive created (Installation.java:211)
            2017-05-31 12:08:11,393 INFO  Instance ExperienceOptimizationLive created in C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimizationLive (DeploymentAgent.java:539)
            2017-05-31 12:08:11,398 INFO  Copied 500/-1 bytes (InputStreamSerializer.java:85)
            2017-05-31 12:08:11,418 INFO  Added role live to instance ExperienceOptimizationLive (Instance.java:232)
            2017-05-31 12:08:11,886 INFO  deployment:kitchen (Watchdog): process finished (ProcessWatchDog.java:24)
            2017-05-31 12:08:19,053 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:08:19,856 INFO  Copied 13827/13827 bytes (InputStreamSerializer.java:85)
            2017-05-31 12:13:38,434 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:13:39,177 INFO  Invoking start with {logLevel=basic, identifier=ExperienceOptimization, fileName=jobs\start-instance-with-variable.kjb} on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:105)
            2017-05-31 12:13:39,192 INFO  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM -Ddata-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\data -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\config -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log -Dcustom-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\custom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\tmp -Dderby.stream.error.file=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log\bizman.db.log -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.fredhopper.util.prefs.XmlPreferencesFactory -Dhttp.keepAlive=false -DKETTLE_HOME=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment -DKETTLE_USER= -DKETTLE_PASSWORD= -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY= -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\plugins,C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\plugins -Didentifier=ExperienceOptimization -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7100 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xmx4000m -Xloggc:C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\log\kitchen.gc.log -cp C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\lib\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\hive\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\JDBC\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\bigdata\pigConf\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\feeds\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\JDBC\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\mondrian\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\mondrian\config\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\pentaho\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\reporting\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\DM\libext\salesforce\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\lib\*; org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -file C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\deployment\jobs\start-instance-with-variable.kjb -level Basic -norep -param:identifier=ExperienceOptimization (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,639 INFO  Copied 475/-1 bytes (InputStreamSerializer.java:85)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,656 INFO  Invoking status on process xmlloader of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,665 INFO  Invoking status on process searchindexer of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,669 INFO  Invoking status on process treebuilder of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,673 INFO  Invoking start with {} on process xmlloader of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:105)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,687 INFO  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Dapp-name=xmlloader -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8103 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/fredhopper/bin/../data/installations/FAS/etc/log4j-cmdline.xml -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS -Ddata-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\data -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\config -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log -Dcustom-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp -Dderby.stream.error.file=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\bizman.db.log -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.fredhopper.util.prefs.XmlPreferencesFactory -Dorg.apache.lucene.FSDirectory.class=org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory -Ddrools.noSkipOnModifyCheck=true -DJEMonitor=true -Xmx400m -Xloggc:C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\xmlloader.gc.log -cp C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\lib\*; com.fredhopper.management.simple.RunHelper --class com.fredhopper.application.XmlLoaderApp --socket-file C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp\xmlloader.socket -- (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,701 INFO  Invoking start with {} on process searchindexer of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:105)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,707 INFO  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Dapp-name=searchindexer -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8104 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/fredhopper/bin/../data/installations/FAS/etc/log4j-cmdline.xml -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS -Ddata-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\data -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\config -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log -Dcustom-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp -Dderby.stream.error.file=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\bizman.db.log -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.fredhopper.util.prefs.XmlPreferencesFactory -Dorg.apache.lucene.FSDirectory.class=org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory -Ddrools.noSkipOnModifyCheck=true -DJEMonitor=true -Xmx900m -Xloggc:C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\searchindexer.gc.log -cp C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\lib\*; com.fredhopper.management.simple.RunHelper --class com.fredhopper.application.SearchIndexApp --socket-file C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp\searchindexer.socket -- (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:59)
            2017-05-31 12:13:44,728 INFO  Invoking start with {} on process treebuilder of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:105)
            2017-05-31 12:13:46,714 INFO  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Dapp-name=treebuilder.catalog01 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8110 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/fredhopper/bin/../data/installations/FAS/etc/log4j-cmdline.xml -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS -Ddata-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\data -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\config -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log -Dcustom-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp -Dderby.stream.error.file=C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\bizman.db.log -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.fredhopper.util.prefs.XmlPreferencesFactory -Dorg.apache.lucene.FSDirectory.class=org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory -Ddrools.noSkipOnModifyCheck=true -DJEMonitor=true -Xmx1200m -Xloggc:C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\log\treebuilder.catalog01.gc.log -cp C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom\*;C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\installations\FAS\lib\*; com.fredhopper.management.simple.RunHelper --class com.fredhopper.application.TreeBuilder --socket-file C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\tmp\treebuilder.catalog01.socket -- -followlog catalog01 (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:59)       
            2017-05-31 12:13:48,456 INFO  Invoking status on process qserver of instance ExperienceOptimization (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:13:51,071 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:28:59,955 INFO  Invoking status on process kitchen of instance deployment (Process.java:102)
            2017-05-31 12:29:00,717 INFO  Copied 15066/15066 bytes (InputStreamSerializer.java:85)
```

Finally the the Fredhopper admin `http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/admin/` is not working.

Whereas when I tried with the default configuration as per Fredhopper learning center with `demo index server` it worked.

Can any one please help me with the Experience Optimzation configuration for SBL Web 8.5.

**Update-1**
Kitchen.log

```
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,528 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic logging
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,530 - Kitchen - Start of run.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,577 - start-instance-with-variable - Start of job execution
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,582 - start-instance-with-variable - Starting entry [Set directories]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,583 - start-instance-with-variable - Starting entry [Read Variable Topology]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,585 - Read Variable Topology - Loading transformation from XML file [../../instances/deployment//transformations/read-variable-topology.ktr]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,664 - read-variable-topology - Dispatching started for transformation [read-variable-topology]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,700 - Generate Rows - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,701 - Read Cluster topology - Opening file: C:\fredhopper\config\topology.txt
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,706 - Read Cluster topology - Finished processing (I=2, O=0, R=0, W=2, U=1, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,739 - Set Variable - Optimization level not specified.  Using default of 9.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,824 - Set Variable - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,875 - Stream lookup - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=3, W=2, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,879 - Wait for all indexer to be ready - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:43,879 - Wait for all indexer to be ready 2 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,039 - Get INDEXER INFO - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=2, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,042 - Copy rows to result - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,044 - start-instance-with-variable - Starting entry [Start single instance]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,195 - start-single-instance - Starting entry [Is live node]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,196 - start-single-instance - Starting entry [Set Variables for Staging]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,196 - Set Variables for Staging - Loading transformation from XML file [../../instances/deployment//transformations/cluster-definition-to-variable.ktr]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,205 - Set variables for one cluster node definition - Dispatching started for transformation [Set variables for one cluster node definition]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,209 - Read from result - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,210 - Calculate Replication port from instance number - Optimization level not specified.  Using default of 9.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,222 - Set Variables - Setting environment variables...
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,222 - Set Variables - Set variable IDENTIFIER to value [ExperienceOptimization]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,222 - Set Variables - Set variable HOST to value [localhost]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,222 - Set Variables - Set variable PORT_SEGMENT to value [1]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,222 - Set Variables - Set variable REPLICATION_INSTANCE to value [-]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,223 - Set Variables - Set variable COMMENTS to value [Indexer and Preview environment for demo setup]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,223 - Set Variables - Set variable ROOT_PORT_REAL to value [7100]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,224 - Set Variables - Set variable ROOT_HOST to value []
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,224 - Calculate Replication port from instance number - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,229 - Set Variables - Finished after 1 rows.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,229 - Set Variables - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,231 - start-single-instance - Starting entry [Remove previous search indices]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,233 - Remove previous search indices - Starting...
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,524 - Remove previous search indices - File 'data/indices/search/indexing' was not found on the server and will not be deleted.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,524 - Remove previous search indices - Finished operation of Job Entry [Remove previous search indices] (result=[true])
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,525 - start-single-instance - Starting entry [Start Indexers]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,527 - Start Indexers - Starting...
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,644 - Start Indexers - Getting files from directory 'config' on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,662 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'xmlloader' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'STOPPED'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,666 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'searchindexer' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'STOPPED'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,671 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'treebuilder' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'STOPPED'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,693 - Start Indexers - Executing 'start' on the 'xmlloader' process of instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:44,715 - Start Indexers - Executing 'start' on the 'searchindexer' process of instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,749 - Start Indexers - Executing 'start' on the 'treebuilder' process of instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,819 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'xmlloader' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'RUNNING'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,953 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'searchindexer' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'RUNNING'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,958 - Start Indexers - Getting status of process 'treebuilder' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'RUNNING'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,958 - Start Indexers - Finished operation of Job Entry [Start Indexers] (result=[true])
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,959 - start-single-instance - Starting entry [Start Business Manager]
            INFO  31-05 12:13:46,963 - Start Business Manager - Starting...
            INFO  31-05 12:13:47,490 - Start Business Manager - Getting status of process 'qserver' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'STOPPED'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:48,449 - Start Business Manager - Executing 'start' on the 'qserver' process of instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:48,458 - Start Business Manager - Getting status of process 'qserver' running on instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded. Status is 'RUNNING'.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:48,486 - Start Business Manager - Getting instance number for instance 'ExperienceOptimization' succeeded.
            INFO  31-05 12:13:48,486 - Start Business Manager - Start checking qserver status on 'http://localhost:8183/status'. Operation timeout is 15 minutes...
            INFO  31-05 12:13:49,861 - Start Business Manager - Cannot open connection to qserver status application on http://localhost:8183/status. Keep trying...
            INFO  31-05 12:14:10,338 - Start Business Manager - Qserver status check returned response 503. Keep trying...
            INFO  31-05 12:14:25,346 - Start Business Manager - Qserver status check returned response 503. Keep trying...
            INFO  31-05 12:28:40,699 - Start Business Manager - Qserver status check returned response 503. Keep trying...
            ERROR 31-05 12:28:55,700 - Start Business Manager - Unable to complete execution, the qserver of instance 'ExperienceOptimization' is still unable to serve requests.
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,700 - Start Business Manager - Finished operation of Job Entry [Start Business Manager] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,703 - start-single-instance - Finished job entry [Start Business Manager] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,703 - start-single-instance - Finished job entry [Start Indexers] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,703 - start-single-instance - Finished job entry [Remove previous search indices] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,703 - start-single-instance - Finished job entry [Set Variables for Staging] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,703 - start-single-instance - Finished job entry [Is live node] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,707 - start-instance-with-variable - Finished job entry [Start single instance] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,708 - start-instance-with-variable - Finished job entry [Read Variable Topology] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,708 - start-instance-with-variable - Finished job entry [Set directories] (result=[false])
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,708 - start-instance-with-variable - Job execution finished
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,709 - Kitchen - Finished!
            ERROR 31-05 12:28:55,709 - Kitchen - Finished with errors
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,709 - Kitchen - Start=2017/05/31 12:13:43.531, Stop=2017/05/31 12:28:55.709
            INFO  31-05 12:28:55,709 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 15 minutes and 12 seconds (912 seconds total).
```

**Kitchen.gc.log**

```
        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
    Memory: 4k page, physical 31999600k(23986548k free), swap 40388208k(16603784k free)
    CommandLine flags: -XX:InitialHeapSize=511993600 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=4194304000 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC 
    1.526: [GC (Allocation Failure)  125952K->7072K(481280K), 0.0102812 secs]
    2.513: [GC (Allocation Failure)  133024K->10117K(481280K), 0.0162525 secs]
    3.120: [GC (Allocation Failure)  136069K->7104K(481280K), 0.0132825 secs]
    3.636: [GC (Allocation Failure)  133056K->9510K(607232K), 0.0294576 secs]
    4.637: [GC (Allocation Failure)  261414K->12126K(607232K), 0.0115732 secs]
    10.272: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold)  113866K->13539K(850432K), 0.0580692 secs]
    10.330: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)  13539K->12092K(731136K), 0.3051527 secs]
```

At the time of command running I was able to access the link Fredhopper/admin link, but with a message `Please wait The Business Manager will be available when the indices are loaded. (This page will refresh in 10 seconds)`. 
And when I tried link fredhopper with Web 8 the triggers were not being loaded in Targeting section.

Answer (score 1):

the stack trace implies that your Fredhopper process is running with insufficient privileges. However the Fredhopper version you're running is not supported by XO 8, as it only runs on `7.5.x` (see [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-60A50714-1D73-4EBF-953A-3E20F63DB3CD&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-60A50714-1D73-4EBF-953A-3E20F63DB3CD.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-60A50714-1D73-4EBF-953A-3E20F63DB3CD))

Comment: This is exactly the issue: you cannot run Fredhopper 8.x with XO -- you have to use a 7.5.x version.

Comment: I tried with version 7.5.1.3 , with the user having Administrator access , still I am facing issue while running the command `bin\instance ExperienceOptimization` . I am updating the logs in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

As the demo index server works fine for you , just for testing purposes can you remove the below jar files once and run the `bin\instance ExperienceOptimization` command

```
configuration-management-rest-extension-1.1.jar
smarttarget_api_extension.jar
```

Once you are able to get it to work, then add the jar files again and run the `bin\instance ExperienceOptimization` command again

I have come across similar issue and got it to work in that way in the past, it was a one time error happened only for the first time after installation in my case

Comment: I tried with this option also, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of using

> "bin\instance  ExperienceOptimization"

, try using

> "bin\deployment-agent-client invoke-command ExperienceOptimization
>   start"